# Reduce length of the bar in Bar chart in Highcharts

Tags: react-native, highcharts, react-highcharts

In react-native project I am using npm package "react-native-highcharts" for plotting a bar graph.
I am facing problem to add  padding between the bar and the yaxis label.

For plotting the graph the code I have used is as below:
https://jsfiddle.net/y2uh60tc/

```
<View style={styles.cardView}>
     <View style={styles.headerView}>
          <Text style={styles.cardTitle}>Competition</Text>
     </View>
     <ChartView style={{ height: 300, marginTop: 5, overflow: 'hidden' }} config={conf} originWhitelist={['']} />
</View>
```

In mobile if i am trying to give padding in +/- values also its not working.

Can someone kindly help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make more space in the plot area, for example by setting `maxPadding` option. To move the labels use `stackLabels.x` property:

```
yAxis: {
    ...
    maxPadding: 0.2,
    stackLabels: {
        ...,
        x: 30
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jx02uw9p/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.stackLabels.x

Comment: Thanks a lot @ppotaczek for the explanation too.